# virtualenv project vs django/rapidsms project

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtualenvwrapper

I am new to whole python django world and currently learning rapidsms. i am at a point where I installed `virtualenvwrapper` and created virtualenv for project `mkvirtualenv projXYZ` and `workon projXYZ`. I have installed django and rapidsms after this. So right now as per my understanding I only have pip, python and virtualenv installed on my local and all project specific tech is installed in virtual env created by name `projXYZ`. Is my understanding correct?

After this as I am following tutorials I am to create new RapidSMS-django project from template. I am confused whether to create this project with same name as `projectXYZ` since I have virtualenv for project or Can it be other project name as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my understanding correct?

Yes, that's right. But as far as I know you can to extend standard setup script and to add some additional default packages. See this [link](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/#creating-your-own-bootstrap-scripts) for detail.

> or Can it be other project name as well.

This could be any other name you like. Virtualenv does not limit you in this way.

Comment: Thank you for helping out. highly appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @neverwalkaloner, the virtualenv and your project can have any name. You might name your project `foo` and the virtualenv you use for that project `bar`. However, you will typically use the same name for both, since you might be working on 10 different projects and have 10 virtualenvs, one for each project, so a convention helps, and the simplest convention is for project and virtualenv to have the same name.

I've written [virtualenv demystified](http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/01/virtualenv-demystified/) which you might find helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much. Article is helpful indeed.